# file-loader with jest and webpack gives me a

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, webpack-file-loader

I am using ace code editor package which uses a webpack-resolver.js file in its package that has inline `file-loader!` in each require statement
e.g.

This works fine for my webpack config and everything builds fine when using it however when I go to use jest, it isn't recognizing the file-loader! and fails

```
require('file-loader!./src-noconflict/ext-beautify.js')
```

Is there something in the jest config to fix this?

I get the following error

```
 Cannot find module 'file-loader!./src-noconflict/ext-beautify.js' from 'webpack-resolver.js'
```

Comment: I have the same problem, our code is using `webpack-resolver` and we're using jest for testing.
The problem is jest (at least in our configuration) is not using webpack to resolve modules. And it has no implementation of `file-loader` which is a webpack feature

Answer (score 15):

I added: `"ace-builds": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ace-builds"` in `Jest` `moduleNameMapper`, and it worked for me.